# Count extra hours for employees using MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

Hello I've problem with sql counting extra hours for employees in MariaDB...
I managed with extra hours based on following rules:

> ::RULES::
>
> =50% extra for: MON - SAT 6-22 [ok]
>
> =100% extra: MON - SAT 22-6 [ok]
>
> sundays and holidays 00-00 (bank holidays with sundays from holidays` table) [KO, not working]

Two tables:

```
hours (id, operator, datetime, time_worked)
holidays (id, date, dt_start, dt_end)
```

sql query:

```
set @foo="marc";
select id, '6-22' as "busineshours", operator, 
datetime as 'start',
TIME_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i:%s') as "START",
TIME_FORMAT((DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL time_worked*60 MINUTE)), '%H:%i:%s') as "STOP",
time_worked*60 as "time_worked_min",
#100%
case when (
(
TIME_FORMAT((DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL time_worked*60 MINUTE)), '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('22:00:00') and TIME('23:59:59')
or
TIME_FORMAT((DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL time_worked*60 MINUTE)), '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('00:00:00') and TIME('05:59:59')
)
and
(
TIME_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('22:00:00') and TIME('23:59:59')
or
TIME_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('00:00:00') and TIME('05:59:59')
)
)
then time_worked*60
else
    case when 
        (
        TIME_FORMAT((DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL time_worked*60 MINUTE)), '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('22:00:00') and TIME('23:59:59') 
        or
        TIME_FORMAT((DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL time_worked*60 MINUTE)), '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('00:00:00') and TIME('05:59:59')
        )
        then
        round(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL time_worked*60 MINUTE)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d 21:59:59")))/60)
    else
    0
end
end
as "100%",
#50%
case when 
TIME_FORMAT((DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL time_worked*60 MINUTE)), '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('06:00:00') and TIME('21:59:59')
and
TIME_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('06:00:00') and TIME('21:59:59')
then time_worked*60
else 

    case when 
        TIME_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN TIME('06:00:00') and TIME('21:59:59')
        then
        TIME_FORMAT(timediff('21:59:59',TIME_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i:%s')), '%i')
    else
    0
end
end
as "50%"

from hours
where 
counted = 0
and
operator = @foo
```

Examples:

- 50% rule

operator johnnyanthony start extra hours at 3:20pm - 4:50pm (90minutes). 
[Acording to rules = 90minutes 50% extra hours.]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcxHk.png)

- 100% rule

operator joanne start extra hours at 3:20pm - 4:50pm (90minutes).
[Acording to rules = 60minutes 100% extra hours.]

[image]

- 50% => should be 100%

operator marc start extra hours at 3:20pm - 4:20pm  (60minutes in New Year's Eve) 
[Acording to rules = 60minutes 100% extra hours.]

[image]

my target: I don't know how to select hours and count them with holidays table.

Comment: Can we start with something simpler? See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I am trying now to use find_in_set() function to check if column hours.datetime = holidays.date

Comment: Although FIND_IN_SET is blisteringly fast, generally, if you find yourself using it, it implies that your schema design is suboptimal

Comment: Yes, but find_in_set duplicate my rows with output 1 or 0

Comment: I'm frankly astounded that this query does what you want it to do. So, well done, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

i copy into a whole column holiday.date. Then I am able to use FIND_IN_SET.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(date SEPARATOR ',') FROM holidays into @holidaydt;
```